# joining 2 different searches in splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

Search 1:

> app="atlas" source="/usr/local/homeaway/atlas-production/logs/*" index="aws_prod_applogs" titan | stats  avg(*responseTime) by date_mday

Search 2

> app="atlas" source="/usr/local/homeaway/atlas-production/logs/*" index="aws_prod_applogs" titan statusCode=200 | stats  avg(*responseTime) by date_mday

How do i join the 2 different search queries?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app="atlas" source="/usr/local/homeaway/atlas-production/logs/*" index="aws_prod_applogs" titan 
| eval result=if(statusCode=200, "Success", "Failure") 
| stats avg(*responseTime) by result, date_mday
```